# NOT NULL constraint failed: mainsite_customer.user_id

Tags: python, django

I just wanna get profile with full form or empty form.

```
def local_cabinet(request):

    user_id = request.user.id

    caruser = Checkout.objects.filter(user=request.user)

    # form = CheckoutForms()

    orders = request.user.orderitem_set.all()
    total_orders = orders.count()

    ready_order = request.user.order_set.all()

    customer = Customer.objects.filter(user=request.user)

    customer_form = CustomerForm()
```

Maybe here's problem I don't know:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
        if customer.exists():
            form = CustomerForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=customer)
        else:
            form = CustomerForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                

    context = {
        'caruser': caruser,
        'orders': orders,
        'total_orders': total_orders,
        'ready_order': ready_order,
        'cat_selected': 0,
        'customer_form': customer_form,
        'customer': customer,
    }

    return render(request, 'localcabinet.html', context=context)
```

I don't know why I get this, maybe because I'm not right at saving the form.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `User` instance in `form`, that you probably need to pass it after `form` creation and before saving it.

You didn't provide model nor forms, but I guess it will look like this:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    ...
    else:
        form = CustomerForm(request.POST)
        form.user = request.user
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    ...
```

Another thing is that you assign queryset instead of single object with `filter` method:

```
customer = Customer.objects.filter(user=request.user)  # gives queryset with probably one object
customer = Customer.objects.get(user=request.user)  # gives an object - but gives Error if there is None or more than one
```

Probably the best approach to get single object is with `try` and `except`:

```
try:
    customer = Customer.objects.get(user=request.user)
except Customer.DoesNotExists:
    customer = None
```

then later instead of `if customer.exists()` you can use simple `if customer`.

Comment: nothing, i get error

Comment: @Platon update your Comment Form and models please

Comment: Also `customer = Customer.objects.filter(user=request.user)` <- here use `get()`, because filter gives you queryset, not single object.